# spring закрыть контекст без вызова cnt.close()

Tags: java, spring, context

Как можно (можно ли) при завершении программы вызывать `destroy-method` без вызова `appContext.close()`?

```
void main(){
appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml"); 

... blablabla...

// завершаю программу без вызова appContext.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно зарегистрировать [Shutdown Hook](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook--).

```
void main(){
appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml"); 
appContext.registerShutdownHook();

... blablabla...

// завершаю программу без вызова appContext.close()
}
```

В этом случае Spring зарегистрирует перехватчик завершения приложения, в котором будет вызвано закрытие контекста если оно не было вызвано ранее. Удобно при наличии нескольких точек выхода из приложения.

Answer (score 0):

*destroy-method* будет выполнятся для *singleton* бинов только при закрытии контекста, для *prototype* вообще не будет выполноятся так как контекст не будет следить за его жизненным циклом

Comment: вопрос в том как выполнить без вызова закрытия контекста

Comment: не претендую на истину, но мне кажется никак, так как синглтоны создаются один раз, и хранятся в контексте, если ты вызовешь дестрой метод, соответственно он закончит жизненый цикл бина. Что же должно прозойти, когда ты заново запросишь бин

Comment: @UladzislauKaminski если будет вызван метод `close()` контекста, то при попытке каких-либо операций с ним(контекстом), после закрытия, например получения бина, будет выброшено `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.